# Proving an inequality about hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-algebras

[image]

This is an inequality whose proof I can't understand. Why does the first step of the proof(the picture below) hold for an arbitrary hermitian matrix? An arbitrary hermitian matrix is not positive semi-definite. Could anyone explain to me in detail? Here $x$ is an arbitrary column vector.

[image]

Comment: This follows from the fact that for an hermitian matrix $A$ you have that $x^\ast A^2 x=(Ax)^\ast(Ax)$. Now calling $Ax=:y$ your inequality simply becomes $0\leq y^\ast y$.

Comment: $x$ should be a unit vector, cannot hold for any vector, different degrees of homogeneity for the terms of the difference.